# Ruby ripper.bundle incompatible library version errors after system restore from backup

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-ripper

After having to restore my whole system from a backup I'm having trouble with my Ruby gems. In particular, I get "incompatible library version" errors in relation to `ripper.bundle`.

Have tried:

1. Reinstalling rbenv via homebrew
2. Reinstalling Ruby via rbenv
3. Reinstalling OpenSSL

The end of the traceback:

```
 1: from /Users/misteruser/Sites/asite/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
 /Users/misteruser/Sites/asite/vendor/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/misteruser/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin18/ripper.bundle (LoadError)
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get around this in the end just by upgrading Ruby from 2.5.0 to 2.6.5

Comment: This often happens when you do an operating system update that breaks some compiled extensions. Look for ".bundle" in the error messages for that hint. It's also worth noting that a later point version of Ruby 2.5 may work here, the Ruby core team will do their utmost to make sure that supported versions of Ruby run on current operating systems.